# Remove dictionary key when the multiple values are the same

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking to remove keys of a dictionary when its values are all the same. In brief, I am trying to remove any cluster with only one species.
My data looks like this:

```
11554   sulc
11554   rubr
11554   rugi
11554   turc
11555   rubr
11555   rugi
11555   sulc
11555   turc
11556   rugi
11556   rugi
11556   rugi
```

The number corresponds to the cluster name, and the second column the name of the species which belongs to it.
In this exemple I would like to remove cluster 11556 (which has only one species).
I used a dictionary, but I am not sure how to remove only the keys which have only one value. And of keep track of them as well!

Any advices?

EDIT add code:

```
cluster = {}
my_file = open('out.txt')
for line in my_file:
       columns = line.strip().split('\t')
       name = columns[0]
       species = columns[1]
       cluster[name] = species
def remove_duplicates(d):
       encountered_entries = set()
       for key, entry in cluster.items():
            if (in encountered_entries:
                 del d[key]
            else:
                 encountered_entries.add(key, entry)
```

Comment: Can you please show the code which you have tried?

Comment: if you are maintaining single value per key then key '11554', '11555'  and '11556' have same value 'rugi', you want to remove all keys having same value you already have in any previous key. right?

Comment: "when its keys are all the same" - you may be misunderstanding how dictionaries work. A dict maps each key to **a** value - a key can't appear twice, or what would `d[that_key]` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant have duplicate keys in python dictionary you may use list of values if a key appears multiple times

```
clusters = {}

my_file = open('out.txt', 'r')
for line in my_file:
    columns = line.strip().split('\t')
    name = columns[0]
    species = columns[1]
    if clusters.get(name) is not None:
        if species not in clusters[name]:
            clusters[name].append(species)
    else:
        clusters[name]=[species]

my_file.close()
my_output_file = open('in.txt', 'w')

for each_cluster_key in clusters.keys():
    if len(clusters[each_cluster_key]) < 2:
        clusters.pop(each_cluster_key, None)
    else:
        for each_species in clusters[each_cluster_key]:
            my_output_file.write(each_cluster_key+'\t'+each_species+'\n')

my_output_file.close()

print clusters
```

the program will print output in a file named in.txt

Comment: This is nice and seems to do the trick, quick question how do I write the dictionary to a text file, I tried f.write(clusters) but not working!

Answer (score 4):

First of all, a Python `dict` cannot have duplicate keys.

But you could have a `dict` from key to a `list` of values.

```
from collections import defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(list)
with open('out.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        clusters[name].append(species)
```

Then you could do this:

```
clusters = {name:species for name, species in clusters.iteritems() if len(set(species)) > 1}

print clusters
```

---

BTW, do you want to keep duplicate species names? If not, you can change `defaultdict(list)` to `defaultdict(set)` and `len(set(species))` to `len(species)`, you would not have duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes  I did not mean duplicate keys but duplicate values within a key

Answer (score 0):

In the below code consist uniq_cluster as a uniq values and repeated_cluster consit all the repeated clusters

```
uniq_cluster =set()
if data['key'] in uniq_cluster:
      repeated_cluster.add(data['key']
      continue
else:
     uniq_cluster.add(data['key']
print uniq_cluster
print repeated_cluster
```